# MS Access Runtime - File Dialog fails

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I hope you can help me out here...
I have a application in MS Access 2013 (`.accdb`). I have a file dialog function on the button click. (`MSGBOX` Functions are for debuging!)

```
Private Sub Browse_btn_Click()
Dim path As String, initialPath As String
Dim fd As Object
MsgBox "Function Starts"
On Error GoTo errhnd

If IsNull(Me.RPE_Txt.value) Then initialPath = "C:\users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\" _
    Else: initialPath = Me.RPE_Txt.value

MsgBox "Setting FD"
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(3)



On Error GoTo errhnd

With fd
        MsgBox "in fd with statement"
        .Title = "RPE File"
        MsgBox "fd.initialview"
        .InitialView = 2
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.csv"
        .InitialFileName = initialPath
        MsgBox "show"
        .Show
        MsgBox "path"
        path = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
MsgBox "end with"
Me.RPE_Txt.value = path

Exit Sub
errhnd:
MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number

End Sub
```

When I run this on MS Access Runtime 2010 I am getting standard RunTime Error when I click the button and Access crashes...

I tried adding references with below code but it was crashing in the attempt..

```
If Application.Version = 14# Then
    MsgBox "Office 2010"
    If Dir("C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSO.DLL") <> "" And Not refExists("OFFICE") Then
        MsgBox "Applying Reference for 2010 Office"
        'Application.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE14\MSO.dll"
        Application.References.AddFromGuid "{398E906A-826B-48DD-9791-549C649CACE5}", 14#, 14#
        MsgBox "Office 2010 Reference Applied!"
    End If

ElseIf Application.Version = 15# Then
    MsgBox "Office 2013"
    If Dir("C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\MSO.dll") <> "" And Not refExists("OFFICE") Then
        MsgBox "Applying Reference for 2013 Office"
        Application.References.AddFromFile "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE15\MSO.dll"
        MsgBox "Office 2013 Reference Applied!"
    End If

End If
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Pete !

Comment: This is not a reference issue, because you've used late binding. It's more likely there's an issue with that Office 2010 installation. Note that you haven't accounted for the user selecting nothing, but that shouldn't make Access crash, especially not when you do select something/

Comment: thanks for the input but how do I get around this? Should I simply re-install the office 2010 on the machine? I can see that `MSO.DLL` library is present in the installation files but something goes wrong...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly, the FileDialog doesn't work in the runtime.

An often referred replacement code can be found here:

[API: Call the standard Windows File Open/Save dialog box](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm)

It's longwinded but it works.